# vector of pair initializer_list visual 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

I've freshly intalled Visual Studio 2017 community and it doesn't accept (doesn't compile) vector of pair intializer list :

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, bool>> vec {
    {1, true}, {2, false}
};
```

It was perfectly valid in Visual 2015.

Did I miss something from the changelog ? I don't think it's been removed from C++17 specification.

Comment: Your example compiles for me in VS2017. What kind of error do you get?

Comment: Okay I've done some modifications to my visual installation because the compiler was also yelling at me about Windows 8.1 sdk and crt related headers ... Installing the Windows 8.1 SDK and the CRT SDK worked for me. :/

Answer (score 0):

You didn't write "=" operator. Change code to

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, bool>> vec = {
    {1, true}, {2, false}
};
```